# Saving struct to clipboard in C++

Tags: c++, string, winapi, struct, clipboard

I have this structure in my C++ code:

```
struct sData
{
    DWORD Number;
    int CurrentNumber;
    bool GameOver;
};
```

I need to save it to Clipboard as a structure from one process. And from other process I need to load it again as the **structure**. I can do it easy with Cstrings/strings but not with **structures**. What do you suggest to me?

This is my method for setting Cstring to Clipboard:

```
bool SetText(CString text)
    {
        CString  source;
        source = text;
        //put your text in source
        if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
        {
            HGLOBAL clipbuffer;
            char * buffer;
            EmptyClipboard();
            clipbuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, source.GetLength() + 1);
            buffer = (char*)GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
            strcpy(buffer, LPCSTR(source));
            GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);
            SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, clipbuffer);
            CloseClipboard();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this is getter:

```
std::string GetText(void) const
    {
        return (const char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
    }
```

Comment: Use RegisterClipboardFormat to register your own format? Don't pretend it's text when it isn't.

Comment: ^or just encode/decode your data into a string.. :)

Comment: You may  be better off using another way to communicate between processes that is a bit more private like shared memory.

Comment: @CyberSpock yes, but request was using clipboard, there are much more better way how to do it, shared memory as you wrote, or sockets, pipes etc. Thank you for an advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register your own clipboard format, then you can store the `struct` data as-is.

```
static UINT CF_MYSTRUCTDATA = RegisterClipboardFormat(TEXT("MyStructData"));

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct sData
{
    DWORD Number;
    int CurrentNumber;
    bool GameOver;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

bool SetData(const sData &data)
{
    if (CF_MYSTRUCTDATA == 0)
        return false;

    bool bOK = false;
    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        if (EmptyClipboard())
        {
            HGLOBAL clipbuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, sizeof(sData));
            if (clipbuffer)
            {
                sData *buffer = (sData*) GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
                if (buffer)
                {
                    *buffer = data;
                    GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);
                    bOK = SetClipboardData(CF_MYSTRUCTDATA, clipbuffer);
                }
                if (!bOK)
                    GlobalFree(clipbuffer);
            }
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }

    return bOK;
}

bool GetData(sData &data) const
{
    if (CF_MYSTRUCTDATA == 0)
        return false;

    bool bOk = false;
    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        HANDLE clipbuffer = GetClipboardData(CF_MYSTRUCTDATA);
        if (clipbuffer)
        {
            sData *buffer = (sData*) GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
            if (buffer)
            {
                data = *buffer;
                GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);
                bOK = true;
            }
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return bOK;
}
```

Alternatively, using some C++ RAII wrappers:

```
struct Clipboard
{
    Clipboard(HWND hWnd = NULL)
    {
        if (!OpenClipboard(hWnd))
            throw std::runtime_error("Error opening clipboard");
    }

    ~Clipboard()
    {
        CloseClipboard();
    }

    void Empty()
    {
        if (!EmptyClipboard())
            throw std::runtime_error("Error emptying clipboard");
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct DataBuffer
    {
        HGLOBAL _hmem;
        bool _free;

        struct Lock
        {
            DataBuffer& _buffer;
            T* _data;

            Lock(DataBuffer &buffer)
                : _buffer(buffer), _locked(false)
            {
                _data = (T*) GlobalLock(_buffer.Get());
                if (!_data)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Error locking memory");
            }

            ~Lock()
            {
                GlobalUnlock(_buffer.Get());
            }

            T& Data() { return *_data; }
        };

        DataBuffer(const T &data)
            : _hmem(NULL), _free(true)
        {
            _hmem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, sizeof(T));
            if (!_hmem)
                throw std::runtime_error("Error allocating memory");
            Lock(*this).Data() = data;
        }

        DataBuffer(HGLOBAL hmem)
            : _hmem(mem), _free(false)
        {
            if (GlobalSize(_hmem)) < sizeof(T))
                throw std::runtime_error("Bad memory size");
        }

        ~DataBuffer()
        {
            if ((_hmem) && (_free))
                GlobalFree(_hmem);
        }

        HGLOBAL Release()
        {
            HGLOBAL tmp = _hmem;
            _hmem = NULL;
            return tmp;
        }

        HGLOBAL Get()
        {
            return _hmem;
        }

        void Copy(T &data)
        {
            data = Lock(*this).Data();
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    void SetData(UINT format, const T &data)
    {
        DataBuffer<T> buffer(data);
        if (!SetClipboardData(format, buffer.Get()))
            throw std::runtime_error("Error setting clipboard data");
        buffer.Release();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void GetData(UINT format, T &data)
    {
        DataBuffer<T> buffer(GetClipboardData(format));
        if (!buffer.Get())
            throw std::runtime_error("Error getting clipboard data");
        buffer.Copy(data);
    }
};
```

```
bool SetData(const sData &data)
{
    if (CF_MYSTRUCTDATA != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Clipboard clipbrd;
            clipbrd.Empty();
            clipbrd.SetData(CF_MYSTRUCTDATA, data);
            return true;
        }
        catch (const std::runtime_error&)    
        {
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool GetData(sData &data) const
{
    if (CF_MYSTRUCTDATA != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Clipboard clipbrd;
            clipbrd.GetData(CF_MYSTRUCTDATA, data);
            return true;
        }
        catch (const std::runtime_error&)
        {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a good solution thank you, only in first row it wrote me an Error: "function call must have a constant value in a constant expression"

Comment: I used your first solution and it works well. Thank you very much.